# Browser shows title even if Title tag is not present in html document

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

I am making an extension where I need to store the title of the web page or the resources on which the extension is accessed. For the resources, I am getting the title as empty though I can see browser does shows the title on the top. I am trying to get the title through the window.document object. I want to know from where to get the title that shows up, even when the title tag is not present. Is this browser specific?

The url of the resource whose title I am trying to access is: http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf

And the source code (I tried this on console):
    var title = window.top.document.title;
This returns me "", Though the browser shows PDF as the title.

Comment: Can you provide the source code of the url and the shown title?

Comment: @marcuse I added the same in the question

Comment: Pdf document is not a html document. The title could also be "inherited" from the page which actually opened the pdf.

Comment: @Teemu Any way to get that title?